# Problem installing packages on my Redhat machine

Tags: rhel, yum

This is what I get

```
$ sudo yum install git-core
file://localhost/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server/repodata/repomd.xml'
Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
No package git-core available.
Nothing to do
$
```

What is wrong here?

---

Update: Current State of the configuration files:

```
$ cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
pkgpolicy=newest
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
metadata_expire=0


[base]
name=Red Hat Linux - Base
baseurl=file://localhost/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server

$ ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
$
```

Comment: Hmm if you cannot install anything then the settings are wrong. I'd go with pbm's answer.

Comment: Deleted my last comment, missed info in your edit. Anyway NJ's answer is correct. If something in the answer isnt working you should elaborate.

Comment: @Lazer: is it Red Hat Enterprise Linux? What version?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what directory do you expect to get to using `file://localhost/tmp/common1/x86_64/redhat/50/base/ga/Server`? A local file should be referenced as `file:///path/to/file`... Why the `localhost` in there? Do you actually have a directory named `localhost` in the root of your server???

Comment: @pbm: `Linux 2.6.18-238.0.0.0.1.el5xen`

Comment: @Lazer: what is the content of `/etc/redhat-release`?

Comment: @pbm: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)`

Comment: @Lazer: I edited my answer. I don't have other ideas. Sorry...

Answer (score 8):

Okay, a couple of things here:

Your repo location is apparently `file://localhost/tmp/` (I'm not sure about using file://localhost/ but I'm assuming that it's a shortcut for going file:///, but the main issue is the use of /tmp in that path.  Files located under /tmp will get cleaned out on reboot (most times).  Which will explain later failures.

So, step 1 is restore your local repository (using the same method as you used to create it the first time, I'd recommend a location other than /tmp if you intend on using it again in the future - remember you edit your repository entry in yum.conf or yum.repos.d/ with the new path) or connect it to RHN (I'm assuming based on the directory structure this repo source you are using is of the RHEL 5 GOLD tree).

Once you have the repository setup, you will need to either install [git from source](http://git-scm.com/), or from [EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux)](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F).

Just to note however:

1. EPEL packages are built against the latest versions of RHEL, so if you are using 5.0 then you may have dependency conflicts, This is why RHN (subscription required) is the best choice for fixing your repository issue.
2. If you aren't using RHEL, then you will need to fix your CentOS/OUL/SL repository configurations by hand, however the EPEL steps are equally valid.

Answer (score 4):

I think that something is wrong with repository settings. Check entries in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` or `/etc/yum.conf` or `/etc/yum/`...

EDIT:

It is obvious that `baseurl` in `base` repo is invalid. I was unable to find proper repositories for RHEL 5.6, but [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#Life_Cycle_Dates) RHEL 5 is still supported so repositories should be available for 5.6 or at least for 5.8 as this is latest version from line 5.x.

I see two options:

- find proper repositories for 5.6 or 5.8 in RH knowledge base
- [add some cd/dvd with packages as repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34115/2661) (Yanick Girouard answer) if you have one

According to [Gilles answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27330/2661) in [Is CentOS exactly the same as RHEL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/is-centos-exactly-the-same-as-rhel) you could also try adding CentOS repositories.

I'm not CentOS user but I found following repository config for CentOS:

```
[base] name=CentOS-5 - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
```

If it return error try to replace `$releasever` by `5`.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are showing, it looks like you want to use a local copy of the RHEL DVD's Server directory and have yum use that as a local repository. This is common practice when your server is either not connected to the internet, or is not registered with RHN. However, you did it wrong.

Here's how I do it:

1. Mount the RHEL DVD, and copy the entire `Server` directory to a sub directory of your choice (other than /tmp). I personally usually use `/repo`
2. Create a new repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d` as follow (name it something like `rhel-local-server.repo`)

   ```
   [rhel-local-server]
   name=RHEL Local Server Repository
   baseurl=file:///repo/Server
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=1
   ```
3. Remove the `[base]` section you've added in your `/etc/yum.conf` file, it doesn't belong there.
4. Run `yum clean all`
5. Run `yum install git-core`

Comment: There' no *git-core* package in rhel 5. It's available in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and named [*git*](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/git.html)

Comment: I assumed it was there, should have checked. Either way, his repo config was incorrect though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'yum clean all'?

Comment: @Steve: yes, same error again.