# Problems installing R on Red Hat 6, requires libjpeg.so.62

Tags: rhel, r

I've been trying to install R on a remote machine using command line. The machine characteristics are

```
uname -a
Linux ###### 2.6.32-71.40.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 3 14:39:16 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)
Release:        6.0
Codename:       Santiago
```

I have installed everything but there seems to be a problem in `libjpeg.so.62`. If I run R installation as:

```
sudo yum install R

Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath-devel = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: R-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-java = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: R-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-devel = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: R-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-devel.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: R-java-devel = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: R-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: R-core-devel = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: R-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-java.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: R-core = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: R-java-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libRmath-devel.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libRmath = 3.2.1-2.el6 for package: libRmath-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: tex(latex) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tex(dvips) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cups for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtk8.5.so()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtcl8.5.so()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXt.so.6()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXmu.so.6()(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-core-devel.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: zlib-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xz-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tk-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tcl-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pcre-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gcc-c++ for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: bzip2-devel for package: R-core-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package R-java-devel.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: java-devel for package: R-java-devel-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libRmath.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package bzip2-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.5-7.el6_0 set to be updated
---> Package cups.x86_64 1:1.4.2-35.el6_0.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: portreserve for package: 1:cups-1.4.2-35.el6_0.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: poppler-utils for package: 1:cups-1.4.2-35.el6_0.1.x86_64
---> Package gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.4-13.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++-devel = 4.4.4-13.el6 for package: gcc-c++-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64
---> Package java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.6.0.0-1.39.b17.el6_0 set to be updated
---> Package libX11-devel.x86_64 0:1.3-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xcb) >= 1.1.92 for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xproto) for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xcb) for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(kbproto) for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp-devel for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXau-devel for package: libX11-devel-1.3-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXmu.x86_64 0:1.0.5-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package libXt.x86_64 0:1.0.7-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package pcre-devel.x86_64 0:7.8-3.1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package tcl.x86_64 1:8.5.7-6.el6 set to be updated
---> Package tcl-devel.x86_64 1:8.5.7-6.el6 set to be updated
---> Package texlive-dvips.x86_64 0:2007-56.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: psutils for package: texlive-dvips-2007-56.el6.x86_64
---> Package texlive-latex.x86_64 0:2007-56.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: texlive-utils = 2007-56.el6 for package: texlive-latex-2007-56.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: texlive-texmf-latex = 2007 for package: texlive-latex-2007-56.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: netpbm-progs for package: texlive-latex-2007-56.el6.x86_64
---> Package tk.x86_64 1:8.5.7-5.el6 set to be updated
---> Package tk-devel.x86_64 1:8.5.7-5.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXft-devel for package: 1:tk-devel-8.5.7-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package xz-devel.x86_64 0:4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el6 set to be updated
---> Package zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.3-25.el6 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXau-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.5-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package libXdmcp-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp = 1.0.3-1.el6 for package: libXdmcp-devel-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp.so.6()(64bit) for package: libXdmcp-devel-1.0.3-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXft-devel.x86_64 0:2.1.13-4.1.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: freetype-devel >= 2.1.9-2 for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fontconfig-devel >= 2.2-1 for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(xrender) for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(freetype2) for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig(fontconfig) for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender-devel for package: libXft-devel-2.1.13-4.1.el6.x86_64
---> Package libstdc++-devel.x86_64 0:4.4.4-13.el6 set to be updated
---> Package libxcb-devel.x86_64 0:1.5-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package netpbm-progs.x86_64 0:10.47.05-11.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: netpbm = 10.47.05-11.el6 for package: netpbm-progs-10.47.05-11.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ghostscript for package: netpbm-progs-10.47.05-11.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnetpbm.so.10()(64bit) for package: netpbm-progs-10.47.05-11.el6.x86_64
---> Package poppler-utils.x86_64 0:0.12.4-3.el6_0.1 set to be updated
---> Package portreserve.x86_64 0:0.0.4-4.el6 set to be updated
---> Package psutils.x86_64 0:1.17-34.el6 set to be updated
---> Package texlive-texmf-latex.noarch 0:2007-35.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: texlive-texmf-errata-latex = 2007 for package: texlive-texmf-latex-2007-35.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: tex-preview for package: texlive-texmf-latex-2007-35.el6.noarch
---> Package texlive-utils.x86_64 0:2007-56.el6 set to be updated
---> Package xorg-x11-proto-devel.noarch 0:7.4-35.el6 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package fontconfig-devel.x86_64 0:2.8.0-3.el6 set to be updated
---> Package freetype-devel.x86_64 0:2.3.11-6.el6_0.2 set to be updated
---> Package ghostscript.x86_64 0:8.70-6.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: urw-fonts >= 1.1 for package: ghostscript-8.70-6.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: ghostscript-fonts for package: ghostscript-8.70-6.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXdmcp.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package libXrender-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.5-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package netpbm.x86_64 0:10.47.05-11.el6 set to be updated
---> Package tex-preview.noarch 0:11.85-10.el6 set to be updated
---> Package texlive-texmf-errata-latex.noarch 0:2007-7.1.el6 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package ghostscript-fonts.noarch 0:5.50-23.1.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-font-utils for package: ghostscript-fonts-5.50-23.1.el6.noarch
---> Package urw-fonts.noarch 0:2.4-10.el6 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.2-10.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libfontenc.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXfont.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-10.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package R-core.x86_64 0:3.2.1-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64
---> Package libXfont.x86_64 0:1.4.1-1.el6 set to be updated
---> Package libfontenc.x86_64 0:1.0.5-2.el6 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-3.2.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

However if you go to the folder `/usr/lib64/` there is a file named `libjpeg.so.62` in it, so I would assume that `libjpeg.so.62` is installed? What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)?

Comment: Yes I think I'm using EPEL, by typing yum repolist it outputs epel                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                      11,746 (and some more repos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On CentOS ([similar to RHEL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/is-centos-exactly-the-same-as-rhel)), `libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit)` [appears to be provided by the `libjpeg-turbo` package](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libjpeg.so.62%28LIBJPEG_6.2%29%2864bit%29&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=).

If it is available on your install *(probably not if it could not be resolved)*, you should be able to install it with:

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo
```

Otherwise, you could download the CentOS 6 package and install that - e.g. with:

```
wget http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/mirror.centos.org/6/os/x86_64/Packages/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm
```

Other package mirrors:

- http://eu-msync.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm
- ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm

*As a alternative*, you could also [add CentOS as a package source](http://cotdp.com/2012/07/installing-centos-packages-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux/), but you shouldn't need to just for one package.

Comment: If you added the repo you probably need to add the [GPG keys](http://www.centos.org/keys/) so it can check against them (you may also need it for some RPM files)

Comment: When I do `sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo` it outputs `No package libjpeg-turbo available` and if I download the package and write `sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm` my terminal outputs `warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY


Public key for libjpeg-turbo-1.2.1-3.el6_5.x86_64.rpm is not installed`. Seems that I need a public key to install it... any ideas?

Comment: Not sure but (sudo) `rpm --import http://eu-msync.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6` may work