# What Fedora version has the same base as RHEL and CentOS?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, version

RHEL is based on Fedora and the other way around. The present or a future Fedora **will be** the base of the **future** RHEL, while the present version of RHEL is based on an **older** Fedora, which is much longer-term, longer tested, with longer support, with rare updates etc, while present Fedora (27) is fast updating.

There must be a past version of Fedora which is/was the equivalent of the present version of RHEL - and [CentOS, which is based on RHEL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27330/32012). Both are now version 7. **What older version of Fedora would correspond to their level?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is documented in [the Fedora documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/fedora-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux/index.html). From the version table there, RHEL 7 is based on Fedora 19 with some changes taken from later versions.

The relationship is quite a bit more complex than a simple table can represent. In particular, the RHEL kernel receives many updates and backports throughout its life, which Fedora kernels don’t (the kernels in supported versions of Fedora are continually updated to the latest upstream kernel).